# How to run Giles?

Tags: .net, unit-testing

I am trying to use [Giles](https://github.com/codereflection/Giles) but to no avail. I tried both VS 2013 and VS 2010 solutions, tried using it from PowerShell and from NuGet etc. I can only find ps1 (no exe). It seems that arguments are the problem. I am invoking it in the following manner:

```
giles.ps1 -s TestGiles.sln
```

tried using full path etc. 
How do I run this tool?

One error that I am getting is:

```
    Giles -s "C:\Users\Dan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestGiles\TestGiles.sln"
    Grr, argh... v0.1.1.6
    Critical Error: System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.

       at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
       at System.Console.GetBufferInfo(Boolean throwOnNoConsole, Boolean& succeeded)
       at System.Console.Clear()
       at Giles.Program.ConsoleSetup()
       at Giles.Program.Main(String[] args)
    Terminating: True
    Giles.exe : 
    At C:\Users\Dan\Documents\Visual Studio `enter code here`2010\Projects\TestGiles\packages\Giles.0.1.6.1\tools\giles.ps1:8 char:2
    + & <<<<  $giles -s $solutionFile
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

    Unhandled Exception: 
    System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.

       at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
       at System.Console.GetBufferInfo(Boolean throwOnNoConsole, Boolean& succeeded)
       at System.Console.Clear()
       at Giles.Program.ConsoleSetup()
       at Giles.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Could you please specify a specific error you are seeing?

Comment: @SageMage I added the stacktrace.

Answer (score 2):

I have just installed it, and was running through "access denied" problems. After some attempts to solve it, I decided to create a project at C:.

Then it worked (the tool runs).
Try doing the same - although you are not facing permission problems, let's start from the most basic scenario. Create e simple console application at the root directory and try running giles on it. My working command line statement looked like

```
giles.exe -s "C:\X\X.sln"
```

(I created the solution at C:\ and named it "X". Visual Studio will create the X directory and place the solution file within.) If this works... then try copying your solution to this project.

Comment: Done that...
Now I am getting:

System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\tools\G
iles\build\ImpromptuInterface.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not
supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
File name: 'file:///C:\tools\Giles\build\ImpromptuInterface.dll' ---> System.Not
SupportedException: An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network locat
ion which would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of
 the .NET Framework.

Comment: from your comment, there must be a problem with the path "C:\tools\G iles" - the space between G and iles. But is looking for a dll in C:\tools... Where did you try to install it this time?